# Getting error: Type argument cannot be inferred from usage when using LINQ to count nested foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a LINQ query for a nested foreach loop.

The loop is as below:

```
var c = 0;            
foreach(var e in elements)
{  
    foreach(var a in e.Attributes)
    {
        if(a.Name=="City" && a.GetValue().ToString() == "Oakland")                                                 
                c += 1;                    
    }
}
```

I am trying to find a count.

I have tried using a LINQ query

```
int d = elements.SelectMany(e => e.Attributes)
                .Count(a => a.Name == "City" && 
                            a.GetValue().ToString() == "Oakland");
```

but I am getting the error:

> The type argument for method Enumerable.SelectMany cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type argument explicitly.

I tried replacing `SelectMany` by `Select` but then I get an error:

> does not contain a definition for Name and no extension method ...

Comment: @sachin - Please edit question and show the types of elements and attributes so this question will be more helpful for people in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `Attributes` is probably `dynamic` (or boxed as `object`) and thus the compiler does not know that it is a collection. Explicitly specify that it is an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
int d = elements.SelectMany(e => (IEnumerable<dynamic>)e.Attributes)
                .Count(a => a.Name == "City" && 
                            a.GetValue().ToString() == "Oakland");
```

Here is the scenario I describe (explicitly specifying the type):
[image]

Comment: Hi Gilad, don't you remember this question from yesterday - highly downvoted, now deleted and apparently re posted here with one of the answers included.

Comment: You are right :) I just hope it won't be deleted for the people that will need this in the future

Comment: Thanks @GiladGreen this is really helpful. Also helps me understand LINQ a bit better..

Comment: @sachin You are welcome :)

Comment: @sachin - please mark as solved by the answer if it helped you solve it

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `Attributes`?

Supposedly it's a collection of some sort.  But collections come in a variety of flavors and it would appear that in this case the compiler can't implicitly determine the type of any given element of that collection.

For example, suppose `Attributes` was of type `IEnumerable<Attribute>`.  In that case the compiler would know that `SelectMany()` *should be* `SelectMany<Attribute>()` and would implicitly determine that for you.

However, in this case it would appear that `Attributes` is something more custom.  For the sake of argument, I'm going to call the type `AttributeCollection`.  The compiler can't determine for certain what kind of elements are *in* that collection, so it doesn't know what type parameter to implicitly use for `SelectMany<?>()`.  So it needs you to specify that type parameter explicitly.

Your clue is here:

```
foreach(var a in e.Attributes)
```

This line compiles fine, and it tells you that `Attributes` is indeed a collection.  More to the point, what you need to determine is the type of `a`.

It may not be entirely intuitive as to *why* this line of code can determine the type of `a`, but `SelectMany()` can't.  I'm sure someone with a deeper knowledge of the inner workings of these things could provide some insights.  But that's neither here nor there really.  All you need to do in order to get going is to determine the type of `a` and use that.

So, for example, if `a` is of type `Attribute` (just an example, I don't know the type, you need to find out in your IDE), then you'd do this:

```
int d = elements.SelectMany<Attribute>(e => e.Attributes)
                .Count(a => a.Name == "City" && a.GetValue().ToString() == "Oakland");
```